# Vue.js change template data

Tags: vue.js

I have the following code:

```
Vue.component('greeting', {
    template: `<h1>{{ greeting }}</h1>`,

    data: function () {
        return {
            greeting: app.text
        }
    },
});

var app = new Vue({
    el: '.app',
    data: {
        text: 'Hello'
    },
    methods: {
        changeText: function () {
            this.text = 'Goodbye'
        }
    }
});
```

So when I call `changeText` method it changes `text` but `greeting` in the component is not updated. I didn't understand if I should use props, watcher or computed property in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass it as a prop to the component:

```
Vue.component('greeting', {
    template: `<h1>{{ greeting }}</h1>`,
    props: ['greeting']
});
```

and the html:

```
<greeting :greeting="text"></greeting>
```